# not getting inserted in to database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here am having two tables named services and payment and am having two forms for inserting values in to it..in services table am having id and customer_id rows and i want to generate those corresponding id values in to the payment table.
This is my services  table

```
id  code     customer_id    particulars     serialno    complaint   
22  ORD00022    16             tv             100         ddfds     
23  ORD00023    19             GH             565          gfdg     
24  ORD00024    15             tv             122         sdfsd     
25  ORD00025    16             cvbcv           5         tgtdfgfg   
26  ORD00026    16             cvbcv           5         tgtdfgfg
```

This is my Payment  table

```
id      order_id    customer_id   actual_amount   paid_amount   balance     type
3          0            0              250.00       100.00       150.00     Cash
4          0            0              250.00       50.00        100.00     Cash
5          0            0              150.00       50.00        100.00     Credit
10         0            0              500.00       500.00       400.00     Credit
```

This is my Payment Add form

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account_control/make_payment/<?php echo $result->code;?>" method="post">

          <div class="box-body">


            <!-- end -->


           <!-- end -->

          <!-- end -->

          <!-- end -->
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Order ID</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="order_id" id="order_id" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $result->id;?>">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer ID</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $result->customer_id;?>">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Amount</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_amount" id="total_amount" placeholder="Total Amount">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Paid Amount</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paid_amount" id="paid_amount" placeholder="Paid Amount">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Balance</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="balance" id="balance" placeholder="Balance">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select name="type" class="form-control">
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
         <!-- end -->


          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
          <div class="box-footer col-md-8  col-md-offset-2">
          <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result->id; ?>">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="margin-left: 17px;">Submit</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Cancel</button>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-footer -->
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </form>
```

This is my controler

```
public function make_payment($code)
{
   $data['active_mn']='';
   $data['active_mn']='';
   if($code){
              $code=$this->uri->segment(3);
              $data['result']=$this->Account_model->view_order_id($code);

            }
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('actual_amount','Amount','required');
      if($this->form_validation->run()==true)
           {

             if($this->Account_model->make_payment())
              {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message','updated successfully');
                redirect('account_control/view_order');
              }
          else
             {
               $this->session->set_flashdata('message','update failed');
               redirect('account_control/edit_order');
              }
           }
    $this->load->view('make_payment',$data);

  }
```

this is my Model

```
 public function make_payment()
  {  

    $paid = $this->input->post('paid_amount');
    $total = $this->input->post('total_amount');
    $balance = $this->input->post('balance');
    $order_id = $this->input->post('order_id');
    $customer_id = $this->input->post('customer_id');

     $data = array('order_id' => $order_id,
    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'actual_amount'=>$total,
    'paid_amount' => $paid,
    'balance' => $balance
);
  print_r($data);

    if($this->db->insert('payment',$data))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }


}
```

when i enter the data the data is not getting inserted and in the place of order_id and customer_id iam getting 0 value

Comment: you sure this is running? `$this->form_validation->run()` if not try to remove it and check if everything works.

Comment: if i give $this->form_validation->run()==true the value is not getting inserted and if i give  like this $this->form_validation->run()==false  am getting like this Error Number: 1048

Column 'order_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `payment` (`order_id`, `customer_id`, `actual_amount`, `paid_amount`, `balance`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/account/application/models/Account_model.php

Line Number: 197

Comment: the order_id value is not posting. check that variable. and check the name of the input. It should be `name="order_id"`

Comment: name i had given order_id itself